# Recursive bytearray hash function

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

I need a function that hashes a list of different inputs (integral datatypes, strings, bytearrays) in a recursive manner.

```
def RecHash(v):    
    isSingleElementOfList = False

    if type(v) is list and len(v) == 1:
            isSingleElementList = True

    if type(v) is not list or isSingleElementOfList:   # if v is a single element
        v0 = v
        if isSingleElementOfList: v0 = v[0]

        if type(v0) is bytearray or v0.__class__.__name__ == 'bytes':
            return hash(v0)
        if type(v0) is int:
           return hash(ToByteArray(v0))
        if type(v0) is str:
            return hash(v0.encode('utf-8'))       

        return bytes()
    else:                               # if v is a list
        res = bytearray()
        for vi in v:
            res +=  RecHash(vi)     # recursion
        return hash(res)            # hash the concatenated hashes
```

and the helper function:

```
def ToByteArray(x):       
    q, r = divmod(BitAbs(x),8)
    q += bool(r)    
    return ToByteArrayN(x, q)

def ToByteArrayN(x, n):

    B = bytearray()

    for i in range(0, int(n)):
        b = x % 256
        x = x // 256                  # // = integer division => floor
        B.insert(0, b)

    return bytes(B)

def BitAbs(i):
     return i.bit_length()
```

It is working fine, however, it's very slow (and interestingly, it's not the `hash()` function that is slowing it down.).

Performance is worst when the list contains mostly numbers, so the `ToByteArray` function also doesn't seem to perform well.

Comment: Your function `BitAbs` is missing, so it is hard to suggest improvements of that part.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer. Using `isinstance` instead of `type` does indeed add a bit of performance. I meanwhile found out, that the recursion itself is a huge problem in python because of the large overhead of function calls. Doing it iteratively instead of recursive for lists in lists, would increase the performance by 100%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @pjz already noted in [his answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/156933/98493), `type(v0)` is slow. However, I would recommend instead to use `isinstance`. This allows to use your class also with derived types. From `help(isinstance)`:

> ```
> isinstance(...)
>     isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool
>
>     Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
>     With a type as second argument, return whether that is the object's type.
>     The form using a tuple, isinstance(x, (A, B, ...)), is a shortcut for
>     isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... (etc.).
> ```

Imagine if I rolled my own `int` class, `Int`, which is derived from the base `int` class:

```
class Int(int):
    pass
```

Your `RecHash` function would not work with this. If you use `isinstance(v0, int)`, though, this would still be working.

```
if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 1:
        isSingleElementList = True

if not isinstance(v, list) or isSingleElementOfList:   # if v is a single element
    v0 = v[0] if isSingleElementOfList else v

    type_v0 = type(v0)
    if isinstance(v0, bytearray) or v0.__class__.__name__ == 'bytes':
        return hash(v0)
    if isinstance(v0, int):
       return hash(ToByteArray(v0))
    if isinstance(v0, str):
        return hash(v0.encode('utf-8'))       
else:                               # if v is a list
    res = bytearray()
    for vi in v:
        res +=  RecHash(vi)     # recursion
    return hash(res)            # hash the concatenated hashes
```

---

Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `lower_case` for variable and function names, instead of `PascalCase` or `camelCase`.

Answer (score 2):

ISTR that `type(x)` is relatively slow.  Try saving it in a local variable:

```
typev = type(v)
if typev is list and len(v) == 1:
        isSingleElementList = True

if typev is not list or isSingleElementOfList:   # if v is a single element
    v0 = v[0] if isSingleElementOfList else v

    type_v0 = type(v0)
    if type_v0 is bytearray or v0.__class__.__name__ == 'bytes':
        return hash(v0)
    if type_v0 is int:
       return hash(ToByteArray(v0))
    if type_v0 is str:
        return hash(v0.encode('utf-8'))       
else:                               # if v is a list
    res = bytearray()
    for vi in v:
        res +=  RecHash(vi)     # recursion
    return hash(res)            # hash the concatenated hashes
```

Also, btw, your code will choke on nested single element lists. Consider `[[[1]]]`